# How do I get a list of records containing only True value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing customer events with various columns. Some events appear more than once. I wanted to put all those events in a list. I did this:

`dup_evets=[df_in['EVENTS'].value_counts()>1]`

This placed all events in a list and added True/False to each event based on the check whether it appears more than 1 time.

How do I remove the False ones from the list?

Comment: Please provide an [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df_in[df_in['EVENTS'].duplicated()]['EVENTS'].tolist()
```

Explained:

```
# Returns Series of booleans, called a mask.
mask = df_in['EVENTS'].duplicated()

# Slice (filter) dataframe based on boolean series, only returning the True ones
df_in[mask]

# Get column you are interested in
df_in[mask]['EVENTS']

# Return list of the values in it
df_in[mask]['EVENTS'].tolist()
```

If you want to have other amounts and not only find duplicates, you can use this:

```
df_in[df_in.groupby(['EVENTS'])['EVENTS'].transform('count')>1]['EVENTS'].tolist()
```

Comment: i'm getting `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer`; isn't that the case for you too? version 1.2.4 if matters

Comment: I tried running:

`dup_events=[df_in['EVENTS'].value_counts()>1]['EVENTS'].tolist()`

and I am getting this error:

**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: @MustafaAydın ahhh, thats why i requested the [mre], ofc '.value_counts()' does not return data of the same size, it already groups the data and provides the grouped value count, therefore the mask does not fit the original dataframe. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: @BoSanders adjusted my answer

Comment: This answers exclude the first occurrence of repeated items???